# Division operator (forward slash) in a dynamic SQL - PL/SQL equivalent needed

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I need to write a dynamic SQL which I am able to easily work out in SQL server but struggling to get its equivalent in Oracle.

```
--SQL Server 
Declare @SQLString nvarchar(200)
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT 20/2'
EXECUTE (@SQLString)

--Oracle equivalent
Declare SQLString NVARCHAR2(4000);
--SQLString := 'Select 20' || '/' || '2 from dual'; --does not work
SQLString := 'SELECT 20/2 FROM dual';   --does not work
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLString;
```

All my searches are either leading to using / for buffer or not very helpful.
I wonder how a division operator (forward slash) can be concatenated to form a dynamic SQL in Oracle please.

Comment: You can only execute PL/SQL inside `BEGIN`/`END`/ blocks.  Perhaps that is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `BEGIN END`; also, `Nvarchar2` is not suitable for `execute immediate`, you need `varchar2`.

This works

```
declare
    SQLString   varchar2(4000);
begin    
    SQLString := 'select 20/2 from dual';
    execute immediate SQLString;
end;
```

but does nothing; here is an hint to handle the result of the query:

```
declare
    SQLString   varchar2(4000);
    vResult     number;
begin    
    SQLString := 'select 20/2 from dual';
    execute immediate SQLString into vResult;
    dbms_output.put_line('RESULT: ' || vResult);
end;
```

I assume this is some exercise or sample code, because here I see no reason to use dynamic SQL; this does the same than the previous code:

```
declare
    vResult     number;
begin    
    select 20/2 into vResult from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('RESULT: ' || vResult);
end;
```